# Laravel 5.1: custom validation with custom error message

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

I have custom validation which I added to my form request as:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        "firstCheckbox" => "required_with_one_of:secondCheckbox,thirdCheckbox",
        ...
    ];
}
```

Rule is that if the user selects `firstCheckbox` then he needs to select at least one more checkbox from given parameters: `secondCheckbox` or `thirdCheckbox`.

To make this happen I added to `AppServiceProvider.php`'s boot function following code:

```
    Validator::extend('required_with_one_of', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $data = $validator->getData();
        foreach ($parameters as $p) {
            if ( array_get($data,$p) != null) {return true;}
        }

        return false;
    });
    Validator::replacer('required_with_one_of', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
        return str_replace(':values', implode(' / ', $parameters), $message);
    });
```

All of this is working fine but if I'm not thinking of something please point it out so I can fix it.

My real problem is with the message. The message I receive is:

**"You must select at least one of the fields: secondCheckbox, thirdCheckbox"**

But what I want is to get message:

**"You must select at least one of the fields: Second Checkbox, Third Checkbox"**

To my `lang\en\validation.php` `attributes[]` I have added

`'secondCheckbox' => 'Second Checkbox'`

`'thirdCheckbox' => 'Third Checkbox'`

values, but this doesn't work because I never replace `$parameters` values in the `Validator::replacer()`.

I have looked at `Validator` class and there is simple function that handle all of this

`$parameters = $this->getAttributeList($parameters);`

but I can't call that from `Validator::replacer()`.

Is there a simple way to call this function from `Validator::replacer()` or should I just create `CustomValidator` class extending the `Validator`.

If the second way is the way to go can someone give me instructions how to do this. I've never really used PHP at this level so, although I have rough idea what to do, I'm not really sure how to do this.